# invariance of the dimension of severi varieties of surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, birational-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Suppose I have a smooth projective surface $S\subset P^n$ embedded by a very ample linear system $|L|$. Consider now the generalized Severi varieties that parametrize curves on $S$ belonging to $|L|$, with a given number of singularities of prescribed type. E.g.: one nodes, two nodes, one cusp, one node and one cusp, one tacnode, one triple point and one node... etc.

My question is: is the dimension of such varieties invariant when the surface undergoes blow-up and blow-down transformations? For example: let $\sigma:\tilde{S}\to S$ be a blow up and $V(L)$ a certain Severi variety associated to $L$, are the dimensions of $V(L)$ and $V(\sigma^*L)$ the same?

Well-posing the question in the case of blow-downs seems a little trickier, but ideas are welcome.

I imagine that possibly one needs some hypothesis of irreducibilty on the curves.

Comment: I am not sure this is a well-posed problem.  For a blowing up $\nu:\widetilde{S}\to S$, are you asking for a comparison of the Severi variety $V_{\delta,\kappa}(L)$ and the Severi variety $V_{\delta,\kappa}(\nu^*L)$, where $\delta$ is the number of nodes and $\kappa$ is the number of cusps?

Comment: Yes, of the dimensions of such varieties. I edit a little the question in order to make it more readable.

Comment: Outside the exceptional divisor, the pair $(\widetilde{S}, \nu^*L)$ is isomorphic to the pair $(S, L)$, so if I am not mistaken the two Severi varieties should be birationally equivalent. Maybe it is more interesting to compare $V_{\delta, \kappa}$ with the Severi variety $V_{\delta, \kappa}(\widetilde{L})$, where $\widetilde{L}$ is the *strict* transform of $L$.

Comment: @Francesco: what is the result that you use in order to conclude that they are iso?

Comment: @IMeasy: you are pulling back $L$, which is very ample, so the general element of $|L|$ will not pass through the points you are blowing up. Therefore it seems to me that curves in $|\nu^*L|$ with $\delta$ nodes and $\kappa$ cusps in general position should be the pullback of curves in $|L|$ with the same singularities, not passing through the blown-up locus. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that the line bundle $\sigma^*L$ is not ample, so by blowing up you change the setup.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: Yes I agree. I wonder if one has to assume irreducibility of the curve.

Comment: @Sasha: very good point. If I don't assume the ampleness from start, anyway apparently the question still has sense.